# How to convert data such as "5may2019" to date?

Tags: r, date

How to convert the data such as "20nov2016" in the date?

the variable was saved as factor;  I did it:

```
df$airdates = as.character(df$airdates)

library(lubridate)
as_date(df$airdates)

tmp2 = gsub("\n", "", df$airdates[1]) %>% trimws() #replaced and removed 
extra marks
tmp2 = gsub("\\.", "", tmp2) #replaced and removed extra marks
tmp2 = gsub(" ", "", tmp2) #replaced and removed extra marks
tmp2 = tolower(tmp2) #data look like "20nov2016"
as.Date(tmp2, format = "%d%h%Y") #in this step it creates NA
```

R refuses to take it as a date and create NA`s. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the `%h`? You can see the format strings in `?strptime`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `as.Date`

```
as.Date("20nov2016", "%d%b%Y")
#[1] "2016-11-20"
```

Or `lubridate`

```
lubridate::dmy("20nov2016")
```

Or `anytime::anydate`

```
anytime::anydate("20nov2016")
```

Comment: Thak you so much